# Xamarin Forms: UI issue when running app on iPad

Tags: xamarin.forms

My app UIs are working fine on mobile screen devices. But when running on big screen devices like tablet the UI is not looking good. It is very difficult to read the text in tablet and icon sizes are also small. If I increase the icon size and font size for the tablet, it also affects small screen devices.

Screenshot:

[image]

See the above screenshot: On iPhone, it is very easy to read the text and view icons. But on the iPad, the text and icons are not in a good visible format.

My app is mainly for kids and so I need icons and text in a good readable form. So how can I solve this problem in all the devices?

Uploaded my XAML file on [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zpaWNOWI4-gd8Fp8FMmvPm3qgbpwQ0pi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very complicated to separate UI for iPhone and iPad in Xamarin.Forms . You could use the class **Device** .

The **Device** class contains a number of properties and methods to help developers customize layout and functionality on a per-platform basis.

In your case , you can use the **Device.Idiom** .

For example if you want to set different font size on iPad and iPhone

```
<Label.FontSize>
   <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
            Phone="20"
            Tablet="40"/>
</Label.FontSize>
```

You can set different value of property in xaml or code behind .For more details you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/device#deviceidiom